# Compile cowboy project ignoring errors

Tags: makefile, erlang, cowboy

I had this working with a modification to ERLC_OPTS, or so I thought.
Had to clean up my erlang.mk and didn't save it.

Where do I add the warnings ok flag?

```
root@marble-pyramid-1:~/tunnel-deploy# make run
erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/cowboy'
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/cowlib'
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
 DEPEND cowlib.d
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
 ERLC   cow_base64url.erl cow_cookie.erl cow_date.erl cow_hpack.erl cow_http.erl cow_http2.erl cow_http_hd.erl cow_http_te.erl cow_mimetypes.erl cow_multipart.erl cow_qs.erl cow_spdy.erl cow_sse.erl cow_uri.erl cow_ws.erl
 APP    cowlib
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/cowlib'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/ranch'
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
 DEPEND ranch.d
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/ranch'
 DEPEND cowboy.d
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
 GEN    rebar.config
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/cowboy'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/jiffy'
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
CC=cc escript enc compile
make -f c_src/Makefile.erlang.mk
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/jiffy'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/jiffy'
 DEPEND jiffy.d
/root/tunnel-deploy/erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/tunnel-deploy/deps/jiffy'
 DEPEND tunnel.d
erlang.mk:26: Please upgrade to GNU Make 4 or later: https://erlang.mk/guide/installation.html
 ERLC   actions.erl board.erl clock.erl door.erl hall.erl join_handler.erl player_status_handler.erl res.erl res_test.erl room.erl room_test.erl s.erl seats.erl table.erl table_info_handler.erl table_play_handler.erl table_test.erl tunnel_app.erl tunnel_sup.erl
compile: warnings being treated as errors
src/actions.erl:2: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
make[1]: *** [ebin/tunnel.app] Error 1
make: *** [app] Error 2
```

I tried adding `-W0` to this:

```
Write(["ERLANG_ARCH = ", rebar_utils:wordsize(), "\nexport ERLANG_ARCH\n"]),
        fun() ->
                Write("ERLC_OPTS = +debug_info -W0\nexport ERLC_OPTS\n"),
                case lists:keyfind(erl_opts, 1, Conf) of
                        false -> ok;
                        {_, ErlOpts} ->
```

but I still get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to filter out the default options Erlang.mk uses for compilation by setting ERLC_OPTS like this:
   `ERLC_OPTS := $(filter-out -Werror,$(ERLC_OPTS))` 
 as per [Erlang.mk user guide](https://erlang.mk/guide/building.html#_compilation_options)